Shouldn't the Ask Question page mention the LEGO in all caps preference?
I see there are edits to questions where the word "lego" are being changed to all caps: "LEGO".
Shouldn't there be a quick little note on the "Ask Question" page to capitalize the word LEGO?
Or do it automatically on every save?
Otherwise, I have a feeling every post is going to end up being edited unless the poster is a frequent visitor to the site.  My two cents.
At the very least, correct the case in the question title window:


@Zhaph-BenDuguid All of the Exchange sites have that as lower case.  Must be the cool thing to do.

Nope, I'm submitting a meta request to change it in light of both our desire to have the word "LEGO" in caps on official text as well as encouraging good question titles ;)

Let's see if we can get it actioned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118059/33051

And yes, apologies for the ironic use of lower case in the question title.

This is lower case across the network.

I've made a few edits where I've replaced Lego with LEGO whilst trying to improve on the post by fixing other spelling/grammar edits or adding tags. I generally don't think capitalising LEGO in an edit is worth doing so unless there are other ways the post can be improved.

The other moderator "Zhaph - Ben Duguid" does edit posts for just the capitalization.  I don't have a problem with that, but there should probably be some helpful tip for posters to follow accepted best practices.  That's all.

Yes, I'll admit one of the edits I made this afternoon were just capitalisations, in the other I changed "Lego" to "The LEGO Group", and in the last one I also added a tag. In general I'd also shy away from just capitalising them, but I was a little bored, it was nearly home time, and I was doing a little tidying ;)

I've been doing a few LEGO-only edits, for mostly the same reasons; but if I can improve the post as well when doing so, I have to agree it's better.
